# Javascript : get all the object where id is like log_XXXX

Tags: javascript

I need to get all the objects whose id matches a specific pattern . How can I do it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Current Browsers:

```js
// DOM collection as proper array
const matches = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id^=log_]'));
```

---

Older Browsers: (IE9+)

```js
// Use Array.prototype.slice to turn the DOM collection into a proper array
var matches = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[id^=log_]'));
```

---

jQuery:

```
$('[id^=log_]')
```

---

Really Old Browsers, no jQuery:

```
var matches = [];
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
  if (elems[i].id.indexOf("log_") == 0)
    matches.push(elems[i]);
}
//matches now is an array of all matching elements.
```

Comment: And if you're not using jQuery?  :P

Comment: Your jQuery selector could be improved. The "star selector" is implicit, you should be using the "starts-with" selector instead of "contains", and the underscore doesn't need escaped: `$("[id^=log_]")`

Comment: @openwonk I try to curate my answers when I notice upvotes or comments and they're dated... :-)  Looking forward to Array.from being more commonly available.

Comment: This brings me too close to what I am looking for. When I logged this object in console, I observed that it prints the entire object and not the ID (which is available when I expand the object). Any ideas on how I can fetch just the ID ?

Comment: @YashSaraiya way late on a response, but `matches.map(m => m.id)` will give you the list of IDs

Comment: There is a complete answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714090/queryselector-wildcard-element-match

Answer (score 3):

Ok, here's a straight JavaScript answer:

```
// a handy function to aid in filtering:
// takes an array and a function, returns another array containing
// only those elements for which f() returns true
function filter(a, f) 
{ 
  var ret = []; 
  for (var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) 
  {
    if ( f(a[i]) ) 
      ret.push(a[i]); 
  }
  return ret;
}

// this collects all elements in the current document
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

// and this filters out all but those that match our pattern
var logElements = filter(elements, function(el) 
  { return /log_/.test(el.id) } ); // simple expression
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be best to use a [JS framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_framework) to accomplish this because they have advanced DOM selector functions that make what you want to do incredibly easy. There are many to choose from but the more popular are [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/), [MooTools](http://mootools.net/), and [Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/).