# How to select elements with attributes that start with something?

Tags: jquery, html, css

A lot of frameworks implement their own attributes (`ng-`, `v-`, `bind-`, etc.) Is there a way to select elements that have attributes starting with some string? (without looping through all elements and their properties)

Comment: Do you want to select elements where the attribute name is ng-, or v-, without any regard as to their value?

Comment: Yes, the attribute name starting with some value like ng- or v-, regardless of the value (or what's after ng-/v- in the name)

Comment: Yer, that's not possible using CSS selectors alone I'm afraid. See this article on using wildcards, but that is just for an attributes value: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714090/queryselector-wildcard-element-match

Comment: Looping through and checking attributes would be the only other way I think. Unless you can work a Regex into querySelectorAll perhaps

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting element by data attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute)

Comment: Not trying to select by data attributes.

Comment: I feel your pain. `data-` attributes are fully supported by JavaScript, yet those frameworks choose not to use them. Why oh why? Still, if they would, they would probably do names like `data-ng-whatever` and you'd have the same problem. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use these methods to do this :

- ### **Padolsey custom filter** (see [Padolsey regexp: filter](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/))

  Let's say you have `<div class="exampleDiv">`, you can catch the div element with `$("div:regex(class, exa.*)")`. (NB: `exa.*` is your regex...)
- ### **Native jQuery selectors**

  `$('[id^=start]')` matches elements with id attribute starting with *start*
  `$('[id$=end]')` matches elements with id attribute ending with *end*

Comment: Not trying to select by values starting with something.