# document.links return only links with specific href?

Tags: javascript

I know that I can return an array like so:

```
var links = document.links.
```

I could then loop through the array for where the href attribute `= /somehref`

My question is is there some nifty shortcut when creating links var? Something to the effect of:

```
var links = document.links[href='/somelink']
```

Thus negating the need for a for loop?

Elements with href='/somelink' can be both `<a>` elements and `<button>` elements. Prefer a lazy, efficient ay to return instances of both into one array, as opposed to running a command twice and combining the arrays

Comment: You could use `document.querySelectorAll("a[href='/somelink']")` to get back a list of the `<a>` nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Trouble is I have both <a> tags and <button> tags. Is there a way I can search through both into one array lazily? As opposed to looking through <a>s first and then >buttons>?

Comment: Yes, you can use a selector that looks for both. (But `<button>` tags don't have "href" attributes.) Note that `document.links` won't include `<button>` elements.

Comment: Ah, sorry yes you're right I was reading the html too quickly. Just one more follow up, if you will. Some links have a trailing slash some do not. Is there a way to account for this in a oner? document.querySelectorAll("a[href='/somelink']") or document.querySelectorAll("a[href='/somelink/']"). Put another way href contains "somestring"?

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714090/queryselector-wildcard-element-match

Comment: The attribute value selector can do that: `[href^="/somelink"]` matches "href" attributes whose value starts with the given string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Get the URL of the element with `id`, example `id="myLink"` in the document:

```
var my_link = document.links.namedItem("myLink").href;
```

Or you can use `querySelectorAll()` like @Pointy mentioned in comment :

```
var my_link = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='/somelink']");
```

Hope this helps.