# Change Javascript for multiple id table

Tags: javascript, html-table, fixed-header-tables

I try to fix header table using this code 
[CODE Here](http://jsfiddle.net/QHQGF/7/), but my real table id is:

```
<table id="table table-chrome table-striped wrapped-results  table-drilldown table-drilldown-cell"/>
```

So how can I change the Javascript to use that?

Comment: Copy paste the code instead of attaching it

Comment: Id's cannot have spaces !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3q8py094/

Create a new variable:

```
var querySelector = 'table[id*=drilldown]';
```

and then replace every reference to `#maintable` with `querySelector`

Dan

Comment: Alternatively use the ID `#table-container` and reference `nextElementSibling` or the next element which is a `<table>`

Comment: yes thx can i do the same method
if table-container contain random digit?
like that  table-container-345 , table-container-163

Comment: That's it. `*=` basically means 'includes' and `^=` means starts with and `$=` means ends with. So, `div[id^=table-container]` means `<div>` with and `id` which starts with `table-container`. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714090/queryselector-wildcard-element-match

Comment: Feel free to 'accept' my answer, if you use it. I still can't comment elsewhere :P