# document.querySelectorAll('a[id="*"]'); and wildcard or regex?

Tags: regex, wildcard, selectors-api

Suppose a HTML document in which there are some internal anchor / bookmarks and other html generic content:

```
<a id='alfa'></a>
  other HTML content
<a id='beta'></a>
  other HTML content
<a id='gamma'></a>
  other HTML content
<a id='delta'></a>
  other HTML content
<a id='omega'></a>
  other HTML content
...
  other HTML content
<a id='etha'></a>
```

***other HTML content***: means anything else even other `<a href='something'>`, **without any id set**.

What I want is a cross (recent) browser solution to get **all anchors with an id set** but not those without any id.

But what I want is, if it is possibile, in pure js, to **select in just one js command, all anchors that have their id attribute set to any generic valute**.

I already know, there is the possibility to get them all, then with a for loop extract those I need, but this is not optimal solution.
I also know https://stackoverflow.com/a/8714421/6508528 to get elements that start, end or contain some ids part.
But what if I don't know any part/sub-string of the id?

I don't know may be something like:

```
var allAnchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[id="*"]');
```

that prevents the need to reprocess the array `allAnchors` after getting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This grabs all anchor elements with an id attr. set:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[id]');
```

This grabs all the anchor elements with no id:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a:not([id])');
```

Comment: Please specify:

This selects all a elements **without** any id or all a elements **with** some id?

I'm asking because I don't understand what does the not operator in that position.

Thanks in advance

Comment: All anchor elements without any id.

Comment: Oh... And for all the anchor elements with an id set?

Comment: Is there any solution for the following question too that is similar subject? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774726/document-queryselectorall-get-innertext-of-all-selected-elements-at-once-pure-ja