# document.querySelectorAll get innerText of ALL selected elements at once pure javascript

Tags: element, innertext, selectors-api

I want to get all innerText of a whole column of a very long html table (random length).
I'm using this code:

```
var tbEls = document.querySelectorAll('#tBodyID tr td:nth-child(cidx)');
```

Where cidx = the column index I want to extract content from.

But such code extracts all the td elements (with the innerText inside them of course).
But it doesn't extract directly all the innerText inside them. Cause of this I have to reprocess the returned tdEls array with a for loop to extract from each tbEls[i] element its own innerText. It works but...

My question is:

In pure JS (no external libraries or frameworks) is it possible to use a more direct approach improving some way **just and only** the querySelectorAll parameter `('#tBodyID tr td:nth-child(cidx)')` to get directly **all the td elements innerText at once** and in just one javascript statement and without the need of reprocessing the returned array with the for loop or anything else?

In other words is there a some kind of innerText selector that can be used to get them all at once without any kind of extra loop?

No problem at all if it is not recognized by old browsers, I'm sorry for them.

What I hope to achieve is something like:

```
var arrTblColInnerText = document.querySelectorAll('#tBodyID tr td:nth-child(cidx):alltd:innerText');
```

I want to get an array similar to:

```
0: value from column cidx cell 0
1: value from column cidx cell 1
2: value from column cidx cell 2
3: value from column cidx cell 3
...
n: value from column cidx cell n
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think one possible response to this question is: el.queryselectorall(arguments) acting "solo" cannot do what asked into the original post cause of the fact queryselectorall's arguments can be css selectors only: so it is not possible to target td text nodes with CSS selectors, because they can target only elements, and text nodes aren’t elements but just nodes and so can’t be selected.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way I found was to convert the nodeList to an array first then use a map:

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("h3 em");
var list = [].slice.call(nodes);
var innertext = list.map(function(e) { return e.innerText; }).join("\n");
```

Comment: It is an interesting approach, shorter than mine, nevertheless I still hope to find every innerText in just one statement, optimizing the queryselectorAll parameter. Nevertheless I vote positively for your response because it is shorter than mine. Unfortunately I'm not sure if the combination of "slice", "map" and "join" is faster and more efficient than the normal for loop I use to reprocess the returned value of querySelector.

Comment: @willy you can inline the vars into à single statement. My version is slower than a for loop because it iterates three times over the collection.

Comment: With modern syntax, you can do this like: `[...document.querySelectorAll('h3 em')].map(o => o.innerText).join('\n');`

Answer (score 14):

Here's a one-liner from 2021. It says to take the NodeList returned from the querySelectorAll and make it an Array, then map the innerText into an array.

`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("h3 em")).map(x => x.innerText)`