# Get href from specific class

Tags: javascript, class, href, getelementsbyclassname

I want to get specific links from my mail and open them in a new window.

I got this at the moment:

```
function OpenHrefsInNewWindow() {

//Get class name
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("confirm_link123");
var i = 0;

while(i < items.length)
{
    //Get a part from the specific link
    if (items[i].href.indexOf("confirm") > -1)
    {
        //If it does, open that URL in a new window.
        window.open(items[i].href, "_blank");
    }

    i++; //Increment i here.
}
}
OpenHrefsInNewWindow();
```

But every time I get a new mail the classname is changing. So I got different classnames every time.
So how can I do, to search only for the beginning of the class and change it in my code?

Any solutions? (:

Comment: Do the class names follow a specific pattern? Is it always `confirm_link<some numbers>`? Are there other links that follow that pattern you don't want opened?

Comment: If the class name is changing, you need a different selector...  We need more info on the element in question...  You will need a `document.querySelectorAll` in that case.

Comment: Try getQuerySelector like in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714090/queryselector-wildcard-element-match

Comment: @LucaKiebel So the confirm_link<some numbers> is every time diffrent and i got it 2 times and the second link i dont want to open just the first one.

Comment: @StevenSpungin but how can i implement that in my code?

Comment: We need more context in order to help you with the selector.  I will post an answer so you can see this.

Comment: @StevenSpungin what do you mean more context? Sorry im new in that :/

Comment: `Context` means more details about your issue, such as the `html` that your script relates to.

Answer (score 0):

Use `class^=` syntax to find classes that `start with`.  To open multiple windows, generate a unique name instead of using `'_blank'`.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('*[class^="confirm_link"]')
console.log(items)

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      for(let i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        console.log(items[i])
        window.open(items[i].getAttribute('href'), 'window' + i)
      }
})
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class = 'foobar' >
    <a class='confirm_link1' href='http://www.google.com'></a>
    <a class='confirm_link2' href='http://www.google.com'></a>
    <a class='confirm_link3' href='http://www.google.com'></a>
  </div>
</div>

<button>click me</button>
```

Your example should look like this:

```
function OpenHrefsInNewWindow() {
  //Get class name
  const items = document.querySelectorAll('*[class^="confirm_link"]')
  var i = 0;

  while (i < items.length) {
    console.log('opening', items[i].getAttribute('href'))
    window.open(items[i].getAttribute('href'), "window" + i);
    i++; //Increment i here.
  }
}
OpenHrefsInNewWindow();
```

Comment: Yeah, but i just want to find the begining of my class if its "confirm_link" than its true, after that it will check the link if it contains "confirm".

Comment: The class is changing but the beginning of the class is every time the same.

Comment: Now it works thanks! But the code stop after it gets the first link and opened it why?

Comment: Please explain 'the code stop'.  Exception?  Freeze?  What does your console say?

Comment: I post the code then the code found one link its opening. But there are 3 more links that the should open.

Comment: Do you have a popup blocker running?

Comment: No im not running a popup blocker.

Comment: You need to use a unique window name to open.  Check out updated answer.  Keep in mind SO snippet will not open windows.

Comment: @faketalent For starters , you have `class*=` instead of `class^=`

Comment: @faketalent remove `document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', ()=>{`  That was just for the snippet demo

Comment: @faketalent you don't need the inner loop `    if (items[i].href.indexOf("confirm") > -1)`

Comment: @faketalent I added your code corrected to the end of my answer.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: I use chrome also and it works.  It sounds like you have a popup blocker or something else limiting your windows.  When I put the example code in an html file with the `div` container, and run it from my desktop, 3 windows open.

Comment: Maybe the mail limited my code? Or the code is not finding the other links?

Comment: I added a console.log to the example in the snippet.  try that.

Comment: R.I.P Google Chrome has it own Popup-Blocker xD Got it now! Thank You <3

Comment: @faketalent  Great!  Don't forget to accept answer, and also delete the answer you posted as example.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know please use ES2015 code instead of ES2016.

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('*[class^="confirm_link"]');
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
 var _href = links[i].getAttribute("href");
 if (_href.indexOf("confirm") > -1) 
    window.open(_href, "_blank");
 }
});
```

use this may be this will be helpful

Comment: Also just opening one window.. :/

Comment: @faketalent you want every anchor in new window?