# How to traverse DOM to find the last ancestor with specific attribute in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

Here is my sample HTML:

```
<div id="parent1" data-attribute="parent">
  <div id="child2" data-attribute="child">
    <div id="grandchild4" data-attribute="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="parent2" data-attribute="parent">
  <div id="child3" data-attribute="child">
    <div id="grandchild1" data-attribute="parent">
      <div id="item1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="child4" data-attribute="parent">
    <div id="grandchild2" data-attribute="child">
      <div id="grandchild3" data-attribute="parent">
        <div id="item2" data-attribute="child">
          <div id="sub1" data-attribute="child">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the current element I'm performing query selection on is `sub1`, how do I find the last ancestor with `data-attribute="parent"`? In this case, the expected result should be `parent2`.

I know `closest()` will return the first match which would be `grandchild3`, but is there like a selector to find the final ancestor? Querying by `id` is not option, since my id's are dynamically created.

Answer (score 0):

First, to find all the ancestors, you can combine two conditions `[data-attribute="parent"]` and `[id^="parent"]`. [More on wildcard selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714090/queryselector-wildcard-element-match)

```
$('div[id^="parent"][data-attribute="parent"]')
```

Now, once you have all the ancestors, the `last()` should give you the immediate one. Please find the snippet below

```js
console.log($('div[id^="parent"][data-attribute="parent"]').last().attr('id'))
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="parent1" data-attribute="parent">
  <div id="child2" data-attribute="child">
    <div id="grandchild4" data-attribute="child">
      grandchild4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="parent2" data-attribute="parent">
  <div id="child3" data-attribute="child">
    <div id="grandchild1" data-attribute="parent">
      grandchild1
      <div id="item1">item1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="child4" data-attribute="parent">
    <div id="grandchild2" data-attribute="child">
      <div id="grandchild3" data-attribute="parent">
        grandchild3
        <div id="item2" data-attribute="child">
          item2
          <div id="sub1" data-attribute="child">
            sub1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own version of `closest` which will give you the last ancestor of the type you require. If you're using jQuery:

```js
$.fn.extend({
  closestTop: function(selection) {
    var el = this;
    var lastKnown = null;
    do {
      lastKnown = el;
      var guess = $(el).parent().length && $(el).parent().closest(selection || '');
      el = guess && guess.length && guess.get(0) || null;
    } while (el != null);
    return $(lastKnown);
  }
});

console.log($('#sub1').closestTop('[data-attribute=parent]'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent1" data-attribute="parent">
  <div id="child2" data-attribute="child">
    <div id="grandchild4" data-attribute="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="parent2" data-attribute="parent">
  <div id="child3" data-attribute="child">
    <div id="grandchild1" data-attribute="parent">
      <div id="item1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="child4" data-attribute="parent">
    <div id="grandchild2" data-attribute="child">
      <div id="grandchild3" data-attribute="parent">
        <div id="item2" data-attribute="child">
          <div id="sub1" data-attribute="child">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write an XPath expression and [evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript) that.

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#sub1');
const xpath = 'ancestor::*[@data-attribute="parent"][last()]';
const result = document.evaluate(xpath, element, null, 
                   XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;

console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="parent1" data-attribute="parent">
  <div id="child2" data-attribute="child">
    <div id="grandchild4" data-attribute="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="parent2" data-attribute="parent">
  <div id="child3" data-attribute="child">
    <div id="grandchild1" data-attribute="parent">
      <div id="item1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="child4" data-attribute="parent">
    <div id="grandchild2" data-attribute="child">
      <div id="grandchild3" data-attribute="parent">
        <div id="item2" data-attribute="child">
          <div id="sub1" data-attribute="child">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It' right???

```
document.getElementById("sub1").addEventListener("click", function(){

  let ancester = this.parentElement;
  let flag = ancester.getAttribute("data-attribute");

  while(flag !== "parent") {
    ancester = ancester.parentElement;
    flag = ancester.getAttribute("data-attribute");
  }

  console.log(ancester);
});
```