# Wrapping Specific Divs in a New Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've got an issue that I can't get my head around on how to achieve it, tried a few different methods on CodePen but not really sure where to start so any advice would be awesome.

I want to find all divs that end with the letter S and wrap them in a new div, then the same for the letters R and L.

The real world scenario is wanting to group jean sizes together in to 'Small', 'Regular' and 'Long' sections on a product page to achieve the look below:

[image]

```
<div class="small__stuff"></div>
<div class="reg__stuff"></div>
<div class="large__stuff"></div>

<div class="content__wrapper">
    <div class="content__container">    
        <div class="content__item">
            <span>30S</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>30R</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>30L</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>32S</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>32R</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>32L</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>34S</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>34R</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>34L</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>36S</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>36R</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>36L</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>38S</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>38R</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>38L</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>40S</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>40R</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>40L</span>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/nickelse/pen/dyPGvJm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: find element by text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321896/jquery-find-element-by-text)

Comment: Sounds like it'd be easier to do this server-side. Where is the data coming from?

Comment: if you have access to the data, i'd normalize it into 3 groups before rendering, that should be more logical (and performant?), otherwise you're getting yourself into a weird loop: 1. get data, 2. render data, 3. find places where the data should be grouped, 4. make necessary changes, 5. render again. The alternative would be 1. get data, 2. normalize data, 3. render data

Comment: Yeah no access to the data, unfortunately, it's for an A/B test so this will change if successful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `.each()`, `.endsWith()` and `.wrap()`.

**Demo:**

```js
$('.content__item').each(function(){
  var text = $(this).find('span').text();
  if(text.endsWith('S')){
    $(this).wrap("<div class='parent_S'></div>") ;
  }
  else if(text.endsWith('R')){
    $(this).wrap("<div class='parent_R'></div>") ;
  }
  else if(text.endsWith('L')){
    $(this).wrap("<div class='parent_L'></div>") ;
  }
});
```

```css
.parent_S{
  color: red;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.parent_R{
  color: green;
}
.parent_L{
  color: blue;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="small__stuff"></div>
<div class="reg__stuff"></div>
<div class="large__stuff"></div>

<div class="content__wrapper">
    <div class="content__container">    
        <div class="content__item">
            <span>30S</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>30R</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>30L</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>32S</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>32R</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>32L</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>34S</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>34R</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>34L</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>36S</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>36R</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>36L</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>38S</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>38R</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>38L</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>40S</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>40R</span>
        </div>

        <div class="content__item">
            <span>40L</span>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, can definitely work with this further too :D

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8714421/9744063) thread.

> `[id$='someId']` will match all ids ending with `someId`.

So basically in your case:

```js
const sDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div[id$="S"]'); // Capital S
const sDivsContainer = document.querySelector('.small__stuff');

[...sDivs].forEach(div => sDivsContainer.appendChild(div));
```