# How do I grab an id element in a form that is constructed as an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, queryselector

I have this in a form:

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="pago[1][8819]">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="pago[2][5241]">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="pago[3][8541]">
```

How do I grab these in order to do a loop?

I've tried:

```
const pago = document.querySelector('#pago');

for (let i = 0; i < pago.length; i++) {
  const element = array[i];
  console.log(element);
}
```

But It does not work (returns NULL).

### Edit:

I've read [this reply here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714090/queryselector-wildcard-element-match), but in this case I shouldn't need to use regex to resolve this. I think it should get sorted with a loop of some kind. In that question, the problem was to find elements that have certain strings in their names, where in this case, I need to loop through numbers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [querySelector, wildcard element match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8714090/queryselector-wildcard-element-match), specifically `[id^='someId'] will match all ids starting with someId`

Comment: You can never use a for loop when you select a element by ID, ids's are unique for the page, this the id attribute needs to be the name attribute, use `.form-check-input` in your querySelectorAll (or give them another class)

Comment: Don't use querySelector when you want to select more than one element, use querySelectorAll.

Comment: @GertB. _"You can never use a for loop when you select a element by ID..."_ - That's not quite right. Yes, ids should be unique. But you're not forced to use `.getElementById()` or `.querySelector()` with an id selector. `.querySelectorAll('input[id^="pago["]')` (+ `.forEach()` or a `for` loop) would definitely work

Comment: @Andreas Ok thats true, but the `[]` characters don't belong in a `id` attribute.

Comment: @GertB. That's only true for [HTML 4.x but not anymore for HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using attribute starts with (`[attr^=value]`) selector:

```js
const pago = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=pago]');

for (let i = 0; i < pago.length; i++) {
  const element = pago[i];
  console.log(element);
}
```

```html
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="pago[1][8819]">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="pago[2][5241]">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="pago[3][8541]">
```